# How to get azure blob storage content in FileInputStream in Java?

Tags: java, spring, azure, cloud, blob

I am working on an API (spring boot). In which i need to return FileInputStream in Response body of get method.

**Expected** -
When front end call the get-files API, a file download prompt should be open on browser.

**Problem** - We can't use blob.downloadToFile method, because it will download the file on local machine(or where APIs are hosted) and we need something using which we can send the File directly to front-end on API call.
However there is another method **blob.download()**, which returns OutputStream which can't be returned on API call.

So is there any way that we can convert that OutputStream to FileInputStream without saving to a actual file on our device.

Example code -

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadBlob() throws URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, StorageException, IOException {
        String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" + "AccountName=" + accountName + ";"
                + "AccountKey=" + accountKey;

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();

        final CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("container name");


        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("image.PNG");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        blob.download(outputStream);
        System.out.println("file downloaded");

        return outputStream;
    }
```

Note- the file can be of any type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution - After hitting the API in browser, your file will be downloaded in browser -

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


@RestController
public class FileDownload {
    @GetMapping(path="/download-file")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(){
        String fileName = "Can not find symbol.docx";
        //azure credentials
        String connection_string = "Connection String of storage account on azure";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connection_string).buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient= blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("Container name");
        System.out.println(containerClient.getBlobContainerName());

        BlobClient blob = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);

        //creating an object of output stream to recieve the file's content from azure blob.
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        blob.download(outputStream);

        //converting it to the inputStream to return
        final byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .headers(headers)
                .body(resource);
    }

}
```